# Second copy of Ubuntu doesn't appear in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a machine running Xubuntu 18.04 and Mint. I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1. Everything seemed ok but it doesn't appear in the list of boot options at startup.

When I previously installed Mint with Xubuntu the Mint option was there immediately.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: OK. Simple. Just select the maintenance option from the boot menu and select grub.

Comment: So now how do I indicate that it's fixed.

Comment: Post the fix as an answer (not comment). Mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: Sorry, Advanced, not Maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is exceedingly easy:

Just select the maintenance option from the boot menu and the options will reveal themselves.

Comment: @waltinator: Self-answer... CV Q instead of A.  **;-)**

Comment: maintenance option? Is this in the GRUB menu (I should read that menu I see every day more carefully if so...) or in BIOS/UEFI?